# Index columns disappeared after lambda function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I wanted to calculate the percent of some object in one hour ('Time') so I have tried to write a lambda function, and I think it does the job, but index columns disappeared, columns that dataframe is grouped by.

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'name', 'time', 'object', 'type'], as_index=True, sort=False)['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'].apply(lambda x: x * 100 / 3600).reset_index()
```

After that code I print `df.columns` and got this:

```
Index([u'index', u'col1', col2', u'col3',
       u'col4', u'col5'],
      dtype='object')
```

If there is a need I am going to write some table with values for each column. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the data you are using or a sample of it that enables us to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.groupby` is used to aggregate data, not to apply a function to multiple columns.

For simple functions, you should look for a vectorised solution. For example:

```
# set up simple dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1], 'name': ['A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'col1': [5, 6, 8], 'col2': [9, 4, 5]})

# apply logic in a vectorised way on multiple columns
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].values * 100 / 3600
```

If you wish to set your index as multiple columns, and are keen to use `pd.DataFrame.apply`, this is possible as two separate steps. For example:

```
df = df.set_index(['id', 'name'])
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x * 100 / 3600)
```

Answer (score 3):

Moving the loop outward, will make the code run significantly faster:

```
for c in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']:
    df[c] *= 100. / 3600
```

This is because the individual loops' calculations will be done in a vectorized way.

This also won't modify the index in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You apply `.reset_index()` which resets the index. Take a look at the `pandas` documentation and you'll see, that `.reset_index()` transfers the index to the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Data from Jpp

```
df[['col1','col2']]*=100/3600
df
Out[110]: 
       col1      col2  id name
0  0.138889  0.250000   1    A
1  0.166667  0.111111   2    B
2  0.222222  0.138889   1    A
```